# Catch multiple commands in one script

Tags: vbscript, command, prompt

I use LANDesk for managing the devices in my company.
This tool is great but it lacks te possibility to e-mail the device owner.

Therefore I created a right-click option called "Sent e-mail". This option executes a bat file. The e-mail adress is the commandline parameter.

If I select lets say 50 devices, the batch file will be executed 50 times. This is annoying, does anyone know how redirect all 50 ex

Comment: Welcome! First, please post the code you want to extend. Next, include only tags related to your question. What's the meaning of "vbscript" tag here?

Comment: This looks like off-topic here. You should emphasize the the batch question a bit more. (+ show code, as said). Or accept the one answer (so far) if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I do not catch where is the problem to send 50 or more arguments to your batch file. If the question is how to loop through multiple and variable amount of arguments, then:

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
    REM --Code goes here--
    ECHO %%A
)
```

I hope this helps.